# Angularjs checkbox checked onload but gives undefined when unchecked first time inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using AngularJS, Ionic (v 1) frameworks. On load of the mobile app screen, the checkboxes are to displayed as checked & then user may check or uncheck the checkboxes. The checkboxes are checked on load fine, however, when first time user unchecks a checkbox then the checkbox status value is undefined even though the checkbox is seen to be unchecked. After this when it is checked then it works fine whereby either the checkbox value is true or false depending upon if user checked it or unchecked it. Below if the html section of the code that is displaying the nested ng-repeat and checkboxes displayed. Also, there are multiple checkboxes that can be displayed and that is why second ng-repeat is used to load all the values for the checkboxes. Below the HTML code is the Javascript functions in controllers.

The togglegroup & isgroupshown functions are used to show or hide the checkboxes when the user clicks on the icon next to Extras.

HTML

```
<form name="list" class="list">
<div ng-repeat="(i, item) in menu_items track by $index">
<div class="item item-divider">
{{item.p_name}}
</div>
<select ng-show="item.Customizable == 1" ng-model="data.cmbIngredient[i]">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select the size</option>
<option ng-repeat="x in item.ProductSizes" value="{{x}}">
{{x.ProductName}}: €{{x.ProductPrice | number:2}}
</option>
</select>
<div>
{{item.p_description}}
</div>
<!-- if the Extras value equates to 1 then the checkbox is displayed-->
<div ng-show="item.Extras == 1">
<i ng-click="toggleGroup(item)" class="icon balanced icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(item) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus-round'"></i> Extras
<label ng-repeat="(j, ext) in item.ExtraDetails track by $index" class="checkbox" ng-show="isGroupShown(item)">

<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="1" ng-change="AddExtras(data.data[j].chkextras[i],item.p_id)" ng-model="data.data[j].chkextras[i]"> {{ext.CIngredientName}}

</label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller functions

```
$scope.AddExtras=function(extraStatus,pid){
if(extraStatus == true){
    //pass it to service
}
else if (extraStatus == false){
    //pass it to a service
}
};
$scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
$scope.shownGroup = null;
} else {
$scope.shownGroup = group;
}
};
$scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
return $scope.shownGroup === group;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the docs for ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) you can clearly read what causes the issue:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

Conclusion: you should either use `ng-checked` or `ng-model` and not mix both.

Comment: Ya Thanks!. However, if I don't use ng-checked then the onload checked status of checkboxes doesn't work. Tried the traditional html ways of using checked. Any thoughts on that please? Thanks again!

Comment: If you want the initial state to be checked you need to make sure that your `ng-model` evaluates to true. In other words you should make sure that this variable `data.data[j].chkextras[i]` is true. Maybe you can set `data.data[j].chkextras[i]` to true in your controller?

Comment: Your suggested direction for solution was helpful. I was able to improvise and achieve the desired result. Will up vote your response. For someone visiting here: As Wilt pointed out - i used a scope variable in ng-model and in controller set it to true or false according to the logic. Please also note that you can't possibly call a function in ng-model rather use a scope variable.

Comment: @Ritz If this answers your question you should consider accepting the answer so others see that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for something like this.
[ng-true/false-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: My understanding is that ng-true/false-value sets those values for the checkbox that can be fetched when check is checked/unchecked. So one can set 1/0 etc. Didn't understand how does it address the problem? Please Thanks!